# How to add code to a C wrapper function generated by SWIG (for Python)

Tags: c, swig

When generating a Python wrapper using SWIG, many C wrapper functions are generated by it. One of them is the following (I have stripped it to the bare minimum):

```
SWIGINTERN PyObject *_wrap_delete_Cursor(PyObject *self, PyObject *args) {

    // some generated C code by SWIG

}
```

My question how can we add more code to this C wrapper function?

Comment: Typemaps are generally the way to add code, but you'll need to provide a specific example of what you are trying to do and why the generated code isn't sufficient.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @MarkTolonen! Since I'm a beginner on SWIG, would you mind to share a code snippet or a link that illustrates the usage of `typemaps` to solve this issue in Python?